# Complex analysis prerequisites for Apostol's Modular Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, soft-question, analytic-number-theory, book-recommendation

I have studied Apostol's Introduction to Analytic Number Theory and it didn't much required Complex Analysis. However, I have studied Complex Analysis from *the* greatest book [Churchill's Complex Variables](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0073383171) but unfortunately it doesn't cover prerequisites for Apostol's second book *Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory*. It uses some knowledge of Complex Analysis which I couldn't find any good book for that.

Not a duplicate question, I am definitely looking for a very readable (esp for self-learning) advance book in Complex Analysis **which covers ALL the prerequisites for Apostol's second book.**

Any right suggestion would be much appreciated.

PS I tried [Remmert's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982213) two volumes [books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387971955) on the subject as they looked nice at first (with good amazon reviews (why?!)) but instead of giving detailed rigorous proofs they were obsessed with history and the German quotes!

**Added** - the book gives an quick review or none at all to the following subjects as if the reader already knows about them:

*doubly periodic functions in Complex Space*

*The Fourier expansions in Complex Space*

*Proof of "If is modular and not identically zero, then in the closure of the 
fundamental region $R_{\Gamma}$, the number of zeros of f is equal to the number of poles" is not understandable.*

Comment: What is something that appears in Apostol that you find doesn't appear in any introductory complex analysis text?

Comment: @davidlowryduda, I added the main problems of the book in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that with [these introductory lecture notes](http://www.math.unipd.it/~pietro/doc/Complex_Analysis/De%20Marco%20-%20BasicComplexAnalysis.pdf) (they starts from the the definition of holomorphic function and arrive to residue theorem/argument principle) and with [these more advanced lecture notes](http://www.math.unipd.it/~pietro/doc/Complex_Analysis/De%20Marco%20-%20Selected%20topics%20of%20Complex%20Analysis2012.pdf), you will be able to tackle any topic involving complex analysis.